# Strict list evaluation in GHCi

Tags: haskell, evaluation, strictness

Consider the program:

```
l = [0..10]
l' = map (+1) [0..10]
```

Running it with GHCi, and typing `:sprint l` and `:sprint l'` will reveal both lists to be unevaluated. However, after running `length l` and `length l'` and then again using `sprint`:

```
l = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
```

and

```
l' = [_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_]
```

I've made similar experiments and tried binding variables to lists in GHCi with `let`, however only in the case of `l` (defined as above in a program top-level) is the list always completely evaluated.

These behaviours all point to an optimisation feature, however I was wondering if there is a more elaborate answer (strategy) 'under-the-hood'.

Comment: Well the *elements* are never evaluated, since we do not need them, and do not make any comparison, equality check with the elements. This has not much to do with a list, it will happen with all datastructures.

Comment: Side note: one potential source of confusion can be eliminated by making the lists monomorphic (`[0 :: Integer ..10]`). That way loading the definitions from a file should have the same effect as entering them at the GHCi prompt.

Comment: I don't see an actual question here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The elements of the original `[0..10]` lists were evaluated in both cases. What was left unevaluated in the `l'` case were the results of applying `(+1)` to the list elements. In contrast, here is what happens if we [map the function strictly](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Control-Monad.html#v:-60--36--33--62-):

```
GHCi> import Control.Monad
GHCi> l'' = (+1) <$!> [0 :: Integer ..10]
GHCi> :sprint l''
l'' = _
GHCi> length l''
11
GHCi> :sprint l''
l'' = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11]
```

(Note that I am specialising the integer literals, so that the absence of the monomorphism restriction in the GHCi prompt doesn't lead to different results from what you get upon loading the code from a file.)

It is worth noting that `enumFromTo` for `Integer` (which is what using the range boils down to), [as implemented by *base*](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/src/GHC.Enum.html#enumDeltaToInteger), evaluates the elements in order to know when to stop generating them. That's to say it is not `length` that forces the list elements, as we'd hope from looking at [its definition](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/src/GHC.List.html#length):

```
length                  :: [a] -> Int
length xs               = lenAcc xs 0

lenAcc          :: [a] -> Int -> Int
lenAcc []     n = n
lenAcc (_:ys) n = lenAcc ys (n+1)
```

To get a better feeling for how `length` behaves here, we might try repeating your experiment with a list generated by using [`replicate`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/src/GHC.List.html#replicate) (which, like `length`, doesn't look at the elements) on a not fully evaluated value:

```
GHCi> n = 2 * (7 :: Integer)  -- let-bindings are lazy.
GHCi> :sprint n
n = _
GHCi> l''' = replicate 3 n
GHCi> :sprint l'''
l''' = _
GHCi> length l'''
3
GHCi> :sprint l'''
l''' = [_,_,_]
```

Comment: I partly disagree with "`enumFromTo` must evaluate the elements". For instance, `eft a b = take (b-a+1) $ iterate succ a` seems a correct implementation to me for `Int`, and produces only `[1,_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_]` after the length is forced. A more contrived example: the "pessimized" `eft a b = map id (eunmFromTo a b)` would also be correct (IMO) and produces unevaluated elements. It's silly, but not impossible to write.

Comment: @chi You're right, of course; the answer has been corrected. I probably shouldn't have tried to get away without mentioning the actual implementation of `enumFromTo @Integer`...